# How can I find the package family name of a desktop app?

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, privacy, camera, gpedit

I am trying to restrict the camera to only specific apps on my Windows 10 Surface with Group Policy. I need the package family name of the app to allow it and I would like to allow Zoom which is a desktop app so it can't be found using the `Get-AppX` cmd-let. Is there any other way that I can allow Zoom to access the camera while the Group Policy is enabled? Zoom cannot access the camera currently and Settings can't allow it because of the group policy. Zoom says that there is no camera found but it is able to find the camera once this policy is turned off. I have tried checking Windows for corruption using `sfc /scannow` and `dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth`.

Here is a screenshot of the Group Policy I'm talking about.
[image]

Sorry if my question is worded weird or is lacking information, I am not very knowledgable with Windows.

Comment: I can only explain that that specific group policy does not control whether or not Zoom is able to access your Camera.  The group policy your asking about only manages UWP applications.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Is there any other identifier that works or is there another group policy/setting to allow it?

Comment: There isn’t a group policy that manages desktop applications access to the camera.